# Unity3D.Не могу связать массив состоящий из элементов типа Color с Random

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d, случайные-числа

Создан массив с элементами типа Color. Не могу понять как задавать рандомное значение каждого элемента при перечислении.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject thePlatform;
public Transform generationPoint;
public float distanceBettween;
public Color[] colors = new Color[2];
Random ranCol = new Random();



private float platformWidth;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    platformWidth = thePlatform.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size.x;

    colors[0] = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
    colors[1] = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(transform.position.x < generationPoint.position.x)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + platformWidth + distanceBettween, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

        Instantiate(thePlatform, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length;i++)
        {
            colors = ranCol(colors[0], colors[1]);
        }



    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю как это у вас вообще работает...но как вариант:

```
for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length;i++) {
    gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[Random.Range(0, colors.Length)];
}
```

- `Random.Range(0, colors.Length)` - задает рандомный индекс от 0 до длины массива.
- `colors[...]` - берет цвет из массива по индексу, который был сгенерирован выше
- `gameObject.renderer.material.color = ...` - цвет материала объекта становится тем, что был выбран в `colors[...]`

---

P.S. я так и не понял зачем вам цикл... возможно он и не нужен

Comment: спасибо, потом буду добавлять элементы

Comment: @Sergey если ответ помог - можно нажать на галку рядом с ответом